# How can i change the texts in my fragments each time? For a quiz app that needs the same fragment for each question

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-fragments

So I am making a quiz app and for each question of course, the layout will look the same but questions and possible answers will be different. I have seen that using fragments in this case would be suitable and i tried learning it but its confusing. Can someone help me with the syntax etc how i can change the text of the questions, buttons when given a questions and a list of answers?

```
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.annotation.Nullable;
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class QuestionFragment extends Fragment {

    Button btnOption1, btnOption2, btnOption3, btnOption4;
    Button btnSubmit;
    TextView txtQuestion;

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View questionFragmentView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.question_fragment, container, false);

        btnOption1 = questionFragmentView.findViewById(R.id.btnOption1);
        btnOption2 = questionFragmentView.findViewById(R.id.btnOption2);
        btnOption3 = questionFragmentView.findViewById(R.id.btnOption3);
        btnOption4 = questionFragmentView.findViewById(R.id.btnOption4);
        btnSubmit = questionFragmentView.findViewById(R.id.btnSubmit);
        txtQuestion = questionFragmentView.findViewById(R.id.txtQuestion);

        return questionFragmentView;
    }
}
```

this is the Fragment which i have created.

[image: and the fragment looks like this:]

How can I change the Question and button texts each time for a new question?

Thank you very much!

Comment: Judging by your app I assume your app needs lots of questions. So using fragments isn't very efficient here. I suggest store your questions/answers in a local database and use a layout animation for displaying the changes.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to use view pager along with fragment for question answer and manage accordingly your requirement.

```
public class QuestionPagerActivity extends ActionBarActivity
    implements ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener {

ViewPager mViewPager;
ArrayList<Question> mQuestions; // create custom model with all quetions and oprions data

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();

    actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    setContentView(R.layout.question_pager_activity);

    FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();

    mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewPagerQuestion);
    mViewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(this);
    mViewPager.setAdapter(new QuestionAdapter(fm));
    onPageSelected(0);

    mQuestions = Quiz.get(getBaseContext()).getQuestions();

    int index = getIntent().getIntExtra(QuestionFragment.EXTRA_QUESTION_INDEX, 0);
    Question q = mQuestions.get(index);
    for (int i = 0; i < mQuestions.size(); i++) {
        if (mQuestions.get(i).getId() == q.getId()) {
            mViewPager.setCurrentItem(i);
        }
    }
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    getWindow().clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);
}

private class QuestionAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {

    private ArrayList<Question> mQuestions;

    private QuestionAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
        mQuestions = Quiz.get(getBaseContext()).getQuestions();
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int i) {
        return  QuestionFragment.newInstance(i);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mQuestions.size();
    }
}

@Override
public void onPageScrolled(int i, float v, int i2) { }

@Override
public void onPageSelected(int i) {
    setTitle(String.format("Question #%s", i + 1));
}

@Override
public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {

    if (state == ViewPager.SCROLL_STATE_IDLE) {
        // Hide the soft keyboard.
        ((InputMethodManager) getSystemService(INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE))
                .hideSoftInputFromWindow(mViewPager.getWindowToken(), 0);

    }
}
```

}

Comment: Do I put this in a new class or in my main activity or where? and what exactly is the function of this code (I’m new to android dev and Java) and thank you very much!

Comment: this is just idea i shared with code snippet like you can use viewpager + fragment to fullfilled your requirement